# Spring thymeleaf problems: exception processing template

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm building a simple web service with spring and thymeleaf. That's the code for now:
Controller:

```
package com.Basi.CheBBellaEmittente.Pages.Control;


@Controller
public class SimpleController {
    @GetMapping("/nuovo-utente")
    public String viewInserisciUtente(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("nuovoUtente", new Utente());
        return "nuovo-utente";
    }

    @PostMapping("/nuovo-utente")
    public void memorizzaUtente(@ModelAttribute Utente utente){
        System.out.println(utente.getId());
    }
}
```

Model:

```
package com.Basi.CheBBellaEmittente.Pages.Model;

public class Utente {
    private String id;
    private String citta=null;
    private String genere;
    private String data_nascita=null;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCitta() {
        return citta;
    }

    public void setCitta(String citta) {
        this.citta = citta;
    }

    public String getGenere() {
        return genere;
    }

    public void setGenere(String genere) {
        this.genere = genere;
    }

    public String getData_nascita() {
        return data_nascita;
    }

    public void setData_nascita(String data_nascita) {
        this.data_nascita = data_nascita;
    }
}
```

html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Inserisci un nuovo utente</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/nuovo-utente}" th:object="${com.Basi.CheBBellaEmittente.Pages.Model.Utente}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Città: <input type="text" th:field="*{citta}" /></p>
        <p>Genere: <input type="text" th:field="*{genere}" /></p>
        <p>Data nascita: <input type="text" th:field="*{data_nascita}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the error:

```
2018-09-21 16:51:40.668 ERROR 3132 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "nuovo-utente": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "com.Basi.CheBBellaEmittente.Pages.Model.Utente" (template: "nuovo-utente" - line 9, col 51)
```

So, what can I do to handle this situation? I don't know what's wrong with this, is a very simple code. Can you give me some advice? I'm supposing is some fold packages issue but I can't understand what.

Answer (score 0):

Since your model attribute is named `nuovoUtente` -- `model.addAttribute("nuovoUtente", new Utente());`, that's what you should be using as your th:object.

`<form action="#" th:action="@{/nuovo-utente}" th:object="${nuovoUtente}" method="post">`

An expression like this: `${com.Basi.CheBBellaEmittente.Pages.Model.Utente}` will be interpreted as:  `com.getBasi().getCheBBellaEmittente().getPages().getModel().getUtente()` -- which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks, but now the post method give me error:
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "nuovo-utente" - line 10, col 32)

Comment: Not really sure what I'm supposed to do about that..? is your original question answered?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you set the name of your model attribute to nuovoUtente so you have to do the next on the html:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/nuovo-utente}" th:object="${nuovoUtente}" method="post">
```

You want to create and submit a form. On the @GetMapping and @PostMapping you have to set different urls.

For example:

@GetMapping(/nuevo-utente-form) and @PostMapping(/nuevo-utente)

In the nuevo-utetente-form.html you write the code of the form, and in nuevo-utente.html you write the code for accept the form.

Comment: I edited my post because I found another error in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
th:object="${com.Basi.CheBBellaEmittente.Pages.Model.Utente}"
```

it should point to actual object *instance* that you pass in your view model, not its class, so probably

th:object="${utente}"

is what it should be.